# C++ project complaining about DLL never mentioned

Tags: c++, boost, dll, linker, linker-errors

I've inherited a C++ project that refuses to link because it can't find a DLL:  'boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'.

This DLL isn't mentioned under Configuration Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies.  Indeed it isn't mentioned under ANY option under Linker.  Editing the project file (*.vcxproj), doesn't show this DLL either.

WHERE is this DLL name coming from??

Comment: one of the souce files has a #pragma comment(lib, "...") in it.

Comment: Good suggestion, but this doesn't occur in the source.

Comment: In the boost source? It most certainly does. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184889/how-does-the-c-linker-know-which-lib-contains-which-functions)

Comment: In MSVC, there is a thing called the linker directive.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648917/no-need-to-manually-specify-input-libs-for-boost-how-is-this-achieved.